# MySQL Query jumping records

Tags: mysql

I've got the following query.

```
SELECT month(DMY) Month, 
  Year(DMY) Year, 
  Date(DMY) Date,
  COD_VENDED,
  @running_total := @running_total + Coalesce(TotalImport, 0) as TotalImport
from
(
  SELECT Days.dmy,
    g.COD_VENDED,
    TotalImport
  FROM Days
  left join
  (
    select FECHA_EMIS,
      COD_VENDED,
      sum(IMPORTE) TotalImport
    from GVA12
    group by Date(FECHA_EMIS), Year(FECHA_EMIS)
  ) g
    on date(Days.DMY) = date(g.FECHA_EMIS)
    and g.COD_VENDED='EX'
    and Month(g.FECHA_EMIS)=Month(curDate())
    and Year(g.FECHA_EMIS)=Year(curDate())
  WHERE month(Days.dmy)=Month(curDate())
) src, (SELECT @running_total := 0 AS dummy) dummy
```

The problem is that it's jumping records in the database.

The problem is replicated in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/253a8/4)

Comment: Can you elaborate on jumping?  What do you mean?

Comment: Well, if you look at the table on the SQLFiddle, you will see that there are records for the 3 of Jan. When I run the query, the 3 of Jan returns 0. That happens alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the problem is with your inner subquery:

```
select FECHA_EMIS,
  COD_VENDED,
  sum(IMPORTE) TotalImport
from GVA12
group by Date(FECHA_EMIS), Year(FECHA_EMIS)
```

You are only grouping on the `Date()` and `Year()` as a result the value of the `COD_VENDED` is not going to be constant.

Then when you get to the next part of your query you filter for only records with:

```
 g.COD_VENDED='EX'
```

So if the subquery returns a value that is not `EX` then they are getting filtered out.

You might want to consider grouping by `COD_VENDED` in the subquery:

```
SELECT month(DMY) Month, 
  Year(DMY) Year, 
  Date(DMY) Date,
  COD_VENDED,
  @running_total := @running_total + Coalesce(TotalImport, 0) as TotalImport
from
(
  SELECT Days.dmy,
    g.COD_VENDED,
    TotalImport
  FROM Days
  left join
  (
    select FECHA_EMIS,
      COD_VENDED,
      sum(IMPORTE) TotalImport
    from GVA12
    group by Date(FECHA_EMIS), Year(FECHA_EMIS), COD_VENDED
  ) g
    on date(Days.DMY) = date(g.FECHA_EMIS)
    and g.COD_VENDED='EX'
    and Month(g.FECHA_EMIS)=Month(curDate())
    and Year(g.FECHA_EMIS)=Year(curDate())
  WHERE month(Days.dmy)=Month(curDate())
) src, (SELECT @running_total := 0 AS dummy) dummy
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/253a8/9)

Comment: Just a question, I was trying to change the IMPORTE to the IMPORTE_GR included in the SQL Fiddle, and I couldn't. Can you see any errors?